# Union together with order by in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I need to get the first column of two tables into one row, sorted by both of those columns.This is what I was able to write, but it is not working.

```
select title from movie 
union 
select reviewer_name from reviewer 
order by title,reviewer_name;
```

Mysql says that reviewer_name is an unknown column.

[image]

Comment: Is there no connection between the reviewer and movie? You want them as two columns of the same row, any reviewer goes with any movie?

Comment: Can you provide sample input and output? Your question asks to get two values into one row, then to sort, and it doesn't make sense to sort just one row. I know I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please send tha movie table ddl and the reviewer ddl, 
what columns exists in both tables?

maybe what you are looking for would be solved with something like this:

```
select 
  m.title, 
  r.reviewer_name 
from 
  movie m, 
  reviewer r
where
 m.movieid = r.movieid 
order by m.title, r.reviewer_name;
```

after the updated question , you could do this:

```
select
  mo.title,
  rv.reviewer_name,
  ra.stars
from
  movie mo,
  reviewer rv,
  rating ra
where
  mo.movieid = ra.movieid
  and
  ra.reviewerid = rv.reviewerid
order by mo.title, rv.reviewer_name
```

I also did this quickly in ms access:

```
SELECT 
  movie.title, 
  reviewer.reviewer_name, 
  rating.stars
FROM reviewer 
  INNER JOIN (movie INNER JOIN rating ON movie.movieid = rating.movieid) 
  ON reviewer.reviewerid = rating.reviwerid
ORDER BY movie.title, reviewer.reviewer_name
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you union two (or more) select statements together, the field names from the first select statement will be used for the output.  So the output will only have a field called "title".  There is no "reviewer_name" field in the output.  That's why you were getting the error.

```
select title 
from movie 

union 

select reviewer_name 
from reviewer 

order by title;
```

Comment: but I need to order it with regarded to both of those columns.

Comment: I just reread.  You want the two values in a single row?  What field joins these two tables?  You will need a JOIN, not a UNION then.

Comment: If there is a field called movie_id that joins the two tables together, than MrSimpleMind's answer is correct.

Comment: check the question again. I have updated it with details. :) Yeah I want them to be in a single row

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
SELECT * FROM (select title from movie union select reviewer_name from reviewer) as f order by title;
```

but i think that a join between movie and reviewer is missing here...

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to help sort

```
SELECT 0 as a, title
FROM movie
UNION
SELECT 1 as a, reviewer_name as title
FROM reviewer
ORDER BY a, title
```